# How to enable url manager in yii?

Tags: php, yii

i have uncommented the following code but it doesn't work it gives me an error 404 not found
when i use

```
> http://localhost:63342/forms/index.php/gii
```

and after commenting the url manager code the path

```
> http://localhost:63342/forms/index.php?r=gii works fine. I am using windows Operating system.

> 
> 
> 'urlManager'=>array(
>     'urlFormat'=>'path',
>     'showScriptName'=>false,
>     'rules'=>array(
>         '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
>         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
>         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
>     ), ),
```

Comment: Try to open ``http://localhost:63342/forms/gii`` instead ``http://localhost:63342/forms/index.php/gii``. Just try to remove ``index.php`` from url

Comment: no this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using apache web server, you can enable mod_rewrite extension end configure .htaccess file in webroot directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```